# mv: cannot overwrite directory with non-directory

Tags: linux, bash, file, move

Is it possible to get around this problem?

I have a situation where I need to move some files to 1 directory below.

```
/a/b/c/d/e/f/g
```

problem is that the filename inside `g/` directory is the same as the directory name

and I receive the following error:

```
mv: cannot overwrite directory `../297534' with non-directory
```

**Example:**
/home/user/data/doc/version/3766/297534 is a directory, inside there is a also a file named 297534

so I need to move this file to be inside /home/user/data/doc/version/3766

**Command**
This is what I am running: (in a for loop)

```
cd /home/user/data/doc/version/3766/297534
mv * ../
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the command you're using, specifically the `mv` command that's failing?

Comment: You are attempting to write a file named `297534` to `..` and there exists a directory `../297534` that causes this error.

Comment: You use 'below' but appear to be moving the files 'up' the tree.  Conventionally, the root is at the top of the tree, not the bottom.  What you're doing, it seems, is `cd /a/b/c/d/e/f/g; mv * ..` or something similar?  The obvious way around the problem is to rename either the file or the directory that conflicts...the hard part is determining in advance when that's necessary.  If neither can be renamed, you're at an impasse — don't try it until you can change the rules.

Comment: I edited the main post

Comment: There's a lot of issues with your question. Do you want to lose duplicate information. What if you move a file to where a file already exists? What about overlaying one directory with another? Is there a reason you just don't want to create a new top-level directory and copy everything down there?

Comment: Yes, i know it's difficult what I want, the problem is those files have been restored from a backup not really to their correct location, so now I have to work with them like this. If the file exists it could be overwritten, no problem, also the last directory should be removed (in the example: /297534)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't force mv to overwrite a directory with a file with the same name.  You'll need to remove that file before you use your mv command.

Comment: Or rename the file; or rename the directory that conflicts with the file name.

Comment: But i have 2k+ cases like this. can you suggest something how to go about it?

Comment: What behavior do you want?  When a file is moved to a directory where a directory has the same name, do you want the directory (including all contents) to be recursively deleted and then replaced with the file?

Answer (score 1):

Add one more layer in your loop.

Replace `mv * ../` with

```
for f in `ls`; do rm -rf ../$f; mv $f ..; done
```

This will ensure that any conflict will be deleted first, assuming that you don't care about the directory you're overwriting.

Note that this *will* blow up if you happen to have a file inside the current directory which matches the current directory's name. For example, if you're in `/home/user/data/doc/version/3766/297534` and you're trying to move a directory called `297534` up. One workaround to this is to add a long suffix to every file, so there's little chance of a match

```
for f in `ls`; do mv $f ../${f}_abcdefg; done
```

Comment: If the file itself is located at `../$f/$f` then doing an `rm -rf ../$f` would delete the file, then try to move it, which would obviously fail